# Como trabalhar efeitos em partes de uma imagem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou querendo mapear uma imagem, dividindo ela em 'n' partes iguais, e aplicar efeitos de "zoom" conforme passar o mouse por cima de cada parte. 
Um exemplo prático seria dividir uma imagem 100x100 em 4 partes iguais de tamanho 25x25. Cada uma destas partes, quando o mouse estiver sobreposto, aumentará levemente de tamanho.
Essa última parte eu sei fazer, mas não tenho uma boa ideia em como dividir a imagem. Estava pensando em usar JS, mas não encontrei nada muito específico. Pelo que eu vi, em geral, usá-se a tag `<map>`, mas não enxergo uma forma de manipular isso massiva e genericamente.

Comment: Taca 4 div e já era. kkkk

Comment: @Drik isso não ajuda muito, pois eu preciso que seja feito para qualquer dimensão de tela. Preciso calcular o tamanho do dispositivo da pessoa e aplicar o efeito.

Comment: mais.. uma div pode se adaptar a qualquer tamanho e dispositivo.

Comment: @Drik você poderia exemplificar como dividir a imagem em 4 usando div?

Comment: Cara, não sei na pratica se vai dar certo.. mais vou passar a lógica para vc pode ser que ajude.. por exemplo: você tem uma imagem 100x100 ok? vc ira deixar ela com position: absolute; e joga 4 div por cima dela com 25x25 cada uma.. dai é só fazer o efeito do zoom quando passar o mouse em cima de cada div.. deixar tudo responsivo e tcharãm!! lembrando que é so uma sugestão não testei pra ver se realmente funciona.. espero que ajude!

Comment: já pensou em cortar a imagem no photoshop? e jogar 4 pedaços dela do html... pode ser um alternativa.. !

Comment: @Drik o photoshop não rola, pois pretendo fazer n recortes na imagem. Não fica viável. E vou analisar o primeiro caso. Posso criar n div's. É uma opção. Obrigado